# Php, DirectoryIterator

Tags: php

I am trying to understand part of the output I get from this code:

```
<?php
class DirectoryReader extends DirectoryIterator
    {

        function __construct($path)
        {

            parent::__construct($path);
        }


        function current()
        {
            return parent::getFileName();
        }

        function valid()
        {
            if(parent::valid())
            {
                if (!parent::isDir())
                {
                    parent::next();
                    return $this->valid();
                }
            return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

    } 

    try
    {

        $it = new DirectoryReader('C:\wamp\www');

        while($it->valid())
        {

            echo $it->current().'<br />';

            $it->next();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'No files Found!<br />';
    }
?>
```

At the code you can see that I pass this path to the constructor: `C:\wamp\www`,

What I don't understand: before I can see all the folders the first line is `.`, the second is `..`, and then I can see the folder names for example:

```
.
..
someFolder
someOtherFolder
```

I know that `.` present the current folder and `..` is getting back at the folders hierarchy, but I can't understand why does it print the `.` then `..` and then the folders?
I really want to understand the action of this iterator, if can some one please help me understand I will be very thankful.

Comment: Well... `DirectoryIterator` iterates through directories. And `.` and `..` are directories... Being confused what you're being confused about.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php

Comment: Thank you all guys i will read the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `parent::isDir()` returns `TRUE` for the dot directories, meaning your own `valid()` method returns `TRUE` for them as well.

You could edit your method to look at whether `isDot()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and respond accordingly.

```
function valid()
{
    return $this->isDir() && !$this->isDot();
}
```

Comment: Thank you salathe, i understand about the FilesystemIterator, but i dont understand why does at the start the "." is printed and then the ".." is printed it should print the folders inside the path i passed to the constructor, if you can tell me what they refer to?

Comment: You already know what they refer to, you mention what they are in the question. They *are* folders "inside" the path that you passed to the constructor.

Comment: But if at the start the "." = "C:\wamp\www" then ".." should be equal to "C:\wamp" then it print the folders inside "C:\wamp\www" now how can he do that when he is inside "C:\wamp", I know its simple but some how i cant understand why thoes dot presented why cant it print the folder names inside the path i passed and thats it, if you can try to explain please...

Comment: The dot folders are special nodes in each directory (see feeela's answer). They are **within** your directory, pointing to itself and the parent directory.  This is why they show up as "inside" the directory.  Several of us have now told you how to ignore those dot directories, which is what it appears you really want to be doing.

Comment: Thank you salathe i got it now, i will be happy if you confirm please, if i understand there is 2 more folders that i can't see 1 folder name is "." and this folder is pointing to for example: itself/someFolder, itself/someOtherFolder the folder named ".." i also cant see but it point to the parent for example at this path ('C:\wamp\www') "." is www/etcFolder and ".." is wamp/etcFolder, so thoes 2 folders("..",".") are **folders** when i call them within a path i getting a reference to the parent or the current directory depends if it is "." or "..", If you can please confirm, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not want to show . and .. (as explained in other excellent answers) this snippet taken directly from the [manual page comments](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Shows us all files and catalogues in directory except "." and "..".

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../moodle') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

---

**Edit**

The `FilesystemIterator` is preferred, over the `DirectoryIterator`. When using the former, the dot files are skipped by default (there is a flag to control this behaviour).

```
<?php

foreach (new FilesystemIterator('../moodle') as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Gahh.. I knew there was another way, just couldn't find it.  Thanks for the edit and Yo! Salathe!

Answer (score 1):

That listing is correct, since `.` and `..` are also (virtual) nodes in each directory. If you want to suppress the output of files/folder beginning with a dot (like Apache does in default configuration), you have to implement an appropriate check by yourself in `valid()` in the given code.

> When a directory is built, it is initially populated with the filename parts of two special files: the '.' and '..' files. The filename part for the '.' file is populated with the inode# of the directory file in which the entry has been made; '.' is a hardlink to the file that implements the current directory.
>
> The filename part for the '..' file is populated with the inode# of the directory file that contains the filename part of the current directory file. '..' is a hardlink to the file that implements the immediate parent of the current directory.
>
> Source: http://linuxgazette.net/105/pitcher.html

Answer (score 1):

It prints the . and .. because that class is only checking if the folder is a directory which both . and .. are

Answer (score 0):

furthermore the result is sorted, that's why '.' comes before '..' and 'some_other_directories'.